# Convert accent characters to normal characters in Liquid

Tags: jekyll, liquid, accent-sensitive

For instance name = `Florian Müllner`, want name to be `Florian MUllner`
How to covert name with accented characters in Liquid?

Read the [replace doc](https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/liquid/reference/filters/string-filters#replace), but was not able to figure out. How to use?

Answer (score 1):

This is my very very dirty solution and far from complete (but works for my needs) with no plugins in Jekyll:

```
{% assign text = 'Müller Pérez' %}
{% include normalize_text.html %}
```

and the included file works as a function:

```
{% assign text = text | replace: 'á', 'a' | replace: 'é', 'e'  | replace: 'í', 'i'  | replace: 'ó', 'o'  | replace: 'ú', 'u' %}
{% assign text = text | replace: 'à', 'a' | replace: 'è, 'e'  | replace: 'ì', 'i'  | replace: 'ò', 'o'  | replace: 'ù', 'u' %}
{% assign text = text | replace: 'ä', 'a' | replace: 'ë', 'e'  | replace: 'ï', 'i'  | replace: 'ö', 'o'  | replace: 'ü', 'u' %}
{% assign text = text | replace: 'â', 'a' | replace: 'ê, 'e'  | replace: 'î', 'i'  | replace: 'ô', 'o'  | replace: 'û', 'u' %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use replace like this.

```
{% assign text = 'Florian Müllner' | replace: "ü", "U" %}
```

Comment: It would be a temporary fix, it would fail if the value of text changes. Need something more dynamic

Comment: That's how the replace string filter works.

Comment: Then you need to handleize the text. Please try this code. 
{% assign text = 'Florian Müllner' | handleize | capitalize | replace: '-',' ' %}

Comment: handleize won't convert accent characters, need an answer somewhat mentioned in this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37511463/14673850